# What is ScaffoldColumn and RegularExpression attributes

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, validation, attributes

I am trying to learn `MVC4` and i've come to this chapter called validation.

I came to know about `DataAnnotations` and they have pretty neat attributes to do some server side validation. In book they have only explained about `[Required]` and `[Datatype]` attribute. However in asp.net website i saw something called `ScaffoldColumn` and `RegularExpression`.

Can someone explain what they are, even though I know little what `RegularExpression` does.
Also are there any other important validation attributes I should know?

Comment: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-validation-to-the-model

Comment: Thanks but I didn't see much about ScaffoldColumn and RegularExpression. I saw some blogs trying to explain but it wasn't that helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scaffold Column dictates if when adding a view based on that datamodel it should/not scaffold the column. So forexample your model's id field is a good candidate for you to specify ScaffoldColumn(false), and other foreign key fields etc.

I you specify a regular expression, then if you scaffold a new view for that model,edit customer for example, a regex or regular expression on field will enforce that entered data must match that format.

Answer (score 0):

You can read about `ScaffoldColumnAttribute Class` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.scaffoldcolumnattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
[MetadataType(typeof(ProductMetadata))]
public partial class Product
{

}

public class ProductMetadata
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(true)]
    public object ProductID;

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public object ThumbnailPhotoFileName;


}
```

And about `RegularExpressionAttribute Class` you can read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
using System;
using System.Web.DynamicData;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;


[MetadataType(typeof(CustomerMetaData))]
public partial class Customer
{


}

public class CustomerMetaData
{

    // Allow up to 40 uppercase and lowercase  
    // characters. Use custom error.
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z''-'\s]{1,40}$", 
         ErrorMessage = "Characters are not allowed.")]
    public object FirstName;

    // Allow up to 40 uppercase and lowercase  
    // characters. Use standard error.
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z''-'\s]{1,40}$")]
    public object LastName;
}
```